# SQL: Select groups that do not contain a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and I have these 3 tables:

EMPLOYEES

```
EMPID | FIRSTNAME
  1   | JOHNNY
  2   | DWAYNE
  3   | TOM
  4   | CHRISTIAN
  5   | JACK
  6   | BRAD
  7   | ADAM
  8   | MATT
  9   | WILL
  10  | JIM
```

AIRCRAFTS

```
AID | NAME
 1  | BOEING 1
 2  | BOEING 2
 3  | BOEING 3
 4  | BOEING 4
 5  | AIRBUS 1
 6  | AIRBUS 2
 7  | LEARJET
 8  | DOUGLAS
 9  | JUMBO
 10 | ILYUSHIN
```

CERTIFIED

```
EMPID | AID
  1   |  1
  1   |  2
  1   |  3
  1   |  4
  4   |  2
  4   |  3
  7   |  1
  7   |  2
  7   |  5
  7   |  6
  8   |  7
  8   |  8
  8   |  9
  2   |  10
  2   |  1
  2   |  9
  3   |  10
  5   |  8
  5   |  9
```

The concept is that there are 10 employees and 10 aircrafts. The CERTIFIED table determines which employee is authorized to pilot which aircrafts. Not all employees are pilots though. What I need is to somehow select all pilots who are not certified to use a Boeing. What I tried but did not work is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPID IN (SELECT EMPID
                FROM CERTIFIED
                WHERE AID NOT IN (SELECT AID FROM AIRCRAFTS WHERE NAME LIKE 'BOEING%'))
```

Which gives these results:

```
JACK
MATT
TOM
ADAM
DWAYNE
```

This is wrong because according to the CERTIFIED table, ADAM and DWAYNE are authorized to pilot at least one Boeing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query...

```
SELECT employees.empid, Max(employees.firstname) AS FirstName 
FROM   certified 
       INNER JOIN employees ON employees.empid = certified.empid 
WHERE  certified.empid NOT IN (SELECT certified.empid 
                               FROM   certified 
                               INNER JOIN aircrafts ON aircrafts.aid = certified.aid 
                               WHERE  aircrafts.NAME LIKE 'BOEING%') 
GROUP  BY employees.empid
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f26d/27/0

Result

```
+-------+-----------+
| EMPID | FirstName |
+-------+-----------+
|     3 | TOM       |
|     5 | JACK      |
|     8 | MATT      |
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 3):

I think your query is giving any employee that is certified on a non-Boeing aircraft -- a subtly different set of people.

For your question, I would go for `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where not exists (select 1
                  from certified c join
                       aircrafts a
                       on c.aid = a.aid
                  where e.empid = c.empid and a.name like '%BOEING%'
                 );
```

Another approach -- if you just want the employee id -- uses aggregation and `having`

```
select e.empid, e.firstname
from employees e join
     certified c
     on e.empid = c.empid join
     aircrafts a
     on c.aid = a.aid
group by e.empid, e.firstname
having sum(case when a.name like '%BOEING%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

I happen to like this method, because it generalizes very easily to other conditions -- such as flies Boeing but not Airbus or flies Learjet and Cessna.

Comment: I tried both your methods. Unfortunately your first returns nothing. Your second approach works perfectly, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use NOT IN the emp that are certified  by Boeing in join with aircrafts

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPID NOT IN (SELECT EMPID
                FROM CERTIFIED c 
                INNER JOIN AIRCRAFTS a ON on a.AID  = c.AID 
                WHERE a.NAME LIKE 'BOEING%')
```

Comment: This is still returning wrong values:
`CHRISTIAN
JIM
JOHNNY
WILL
BRAD`